# Slow query with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure which runs pretty slow (6 sec) using the following JOIN:

```
JOIN tariffs t ON 
(LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`,7) = t.numberrange 
OR LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`,8) = t.numberrange)
```

Without the above JOIN the query runs at 1.5 sec.
Any way how to improve the performance? Full stored procedure below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetHourStats`(IN _ID INT, IN _YEAR INT, IN _MONTH INT, IN _DAY INT)
BEGIN

set @_START = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date(_YEAR * 10000 + _MONTH * 100 + _DAY * 1)); 
set @_END = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_add(date(_YEAR * 10000 + _MONTH * 100 + _DAY * 1), interval 1 day));

SELECT h.idhour, h.`hour` as 'hour', innumber, count(*) as `count`, sum(talktime) as `duration` FROM (
     SELECT 
        `cdrs`.`dcustomer` AS `dcustomer`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 2) = "01" OR LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 2) = "02") THEN '01-02'
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 2) = "03") THEN '03'
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 2) = "05") THEN '05'
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 2) = "06") THEN '06'
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 2) = "07") THEN '07'
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 3) = "080") THEN '080'
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 3) = "084") THEN '084'
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 3) = "087") THEN '087'
            WHEN (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`, 2) = "09") THEN '09'
        END) AS 'innumber',
        FROM_UNIXTIME(`cdrs`.`start`) AS `start`,
         (`cdrs`.`end` - `cdrs`.`start`) AS `duration`,
         `cdrs`.`cnumber` AS `calling`,
         `cdrs`.`talktime` AS `talktime`
    FROM `cdrs`
    JOIN tariffs t ON (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`,7) = t.numberrange OR LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`,8) = t.numberrange)
    WHERE `cdrs`.`start` >= @_START and `cdrs`.`start` < @_END
    AND `cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external'
    AND `cdrs`.`talktime` >= 5 
    AND `cdrs`.`status` = 'answer'
    AND CHAR_LENGTH(`cdrs`.`cnumber`) = 11
    GROUP BY callid
   ) cdr 

   JOIN customers c ON c.id = cdr.dcustomer
   LEFT JOIN hub.hours h ON HOUR(cdr.`start`) = h.idhour

    WHERE (c.parent = _ID or cdr.dcustomer = _ID or c.parent IN 
        (SELECT id FROM customers WHERE parent = _ID))

   GROUP BY h.idhour, cdr.innumber
   ORDER BY h.idhour;

END
```

**Q:** How can I make the above stored procedure run faster?

Comment: You could add an indexed column that only stores the first two or three digits.

Comment: Obviously your table design isn't good. cnumber is not a mere number but its parts have meanings. This makes querying the data slow. Re-design your tables such that separate data gets stored separately and queries will be much faster (proper indexing provided, of course).

Comment: Why you do not change `JOIN tariffs t ON` To `LEFT JOIN tariffs t ON` ?
I think you will get better performance

Answer (score 1):

```
JOIN tariffs t ON 
        (LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`,7) = t.numberrange 
      OR LEFT(`cdrs`.`cnumber`,8) = t.numberrange)
```

This might give you the same set:

```
JOIN tariffs t 
      ON cdrs.cnumber LIKE CONCAT(t.numberrange, '%')
```

It fails if numberrange is not 7 or 8 characters long, but perhaps that 'cannot' happen.  Perhaps adding this somewhere would take care of that:

```
 AND LENGTH(t.numberrange) BETWEEN 7 AND 8

 INDEX(numberrange) -- no longer useful
 INDEX(cnumber) -- may be useful here.
```

Comment: This improves the response, but not by much, with less than 1 second gained. Adding an index on `cnumber` does seem to help, but on simple queries, while on the join that index is not being used. Any ideas on how to use the index on the above join? I'll post the result of the explain statement if needed.

Comment: "on simple queries" -- There are other queries?  One cannot build the best INDEX(es) without considering all the queries.